# Assetic did not work if use_controller is set to true

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I will try to explain my problem. Assetic stop to work if `use_controller` is set to true, it runs Ok before I actualized my symfony installation to 2.2.3 but now, If I put a filter like compass it is not apply if I set `use_controller` to true. If I set `use_controller` to false and manually dump the assets with `console assetic:dump` everything works OK.

This is my config_dev.yml file:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: true
    #bundles:        [ ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:    ~
        compass:
            plugins: ['zurb-foundation']
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"            
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

This is my stylesheet.html.twig file:

```
{% stylesheets '@revenge_styles' filter='compass' output='css/main.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

This is my assets.yml file:

```
assetic:
    assets:        
        revenge_scripts:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/revenge.js'
        revenge_styles:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/css/main.scss'
```

And finally, this is my main.scss file:

```
/* Main styleshet */
@import "compass/css3/border-radius";

div#intro {
    @include border-radius(10px, 10px);    
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Helvetica, arial";
}
```

Anyone has encountered a similar problem? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `Assetic stop to work `?

Comment: The main.scss file is converted to main.css, but the filter compass is not applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a global filter.

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    filters:
        compass:
            apply_to: "\.scss$"
```

And remove the `filter='compass'`

Issue: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/101